# Vue router not firing if only slug changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

For some reason, in my Vue app I am having issues with the router when the linked page is only changing the slug. For example

I have the following links

```
<router-link :to="{ path: '/tag/tag2' }">Tag 2</router-link>
<router-link :to="{ path: '/tag/tag3' }">Tag 3</router-link>
<router-link :to="{ path: '/category/cat1' }">Category 1</router-link>
```

which are processed by `router`

```
{
  path: '/tag/:slug',
  name: 'Tag',
  component: () => import('./views/tag')
}
```

inside `views/tag.vue` when it loads it does an `axios` request to get all the tags. Same functionality for category etc

Lets say the current URL is `http://test.com/tag/tag1`

If you click on the link for `Tag 2` the URL will change, but nothing else happens. No `axios` calls etc.

If I click on `Tag 3` the URL will change, but nothing else happens. No `axios` calls etc.

If I click on `Category 1` then the url changes, page loads up the category view and fires off its axis request.

Why does it have issues if only the slug is changing?

Comment: I'm guessing I just add a watcher for the slug and fire off requests?

Comment: You can do that. [Here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes) is the complete explanation in the official docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your axios calls are located in one of component's lifecycle hooks (i.e. `beforeCreate`). The problem is that Vue Router tries to reuse components wherever it is possible. In your case, going from `/tag/tag1` to `/tag/tag2`, the only thing that changes is parameter so it's still the same component and the router does not recreate it again.

There are two solutions:

1. Put the axios calls to `beforeRouteUpdate` hook meaning they will be fired every time route in the component changes.
2. Add `key` attribute to `router-view`, which will make the router to recreate every component.

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

Source: [A post from a member of the core team of Vue'js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1490#issuecomment-306029174)

Comment: Thanks Konrad, super helpful

Comment: This is working in a regular component, but I have an injected mitt bus which I use to emit event which executes an axios call and fill in vuex store. The whole process is in setup() method and the initialize call is in created() method. Any idea how can I solve this issue?  (I tried beforeRouteUpdate and it's not emitting the event and created,mounted it emits and works as expected). Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Vue Router warn]: Component "default" in record with path "/fgbs.blog/articles/:slug" is a function that does not return a Promise. If you were passing a functional component, make sure to add a "displayName" to the component. This will break in production if not fixed.